# Iframe is blocking usage

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, iframe, create-react-app

We have a react application in which we have integrated a camera to record video that has been deployed on AWS with SSL configuration. We are integrating this react app in WordPress by embedding the HTTPS URL of the deployed react app in an iframe and adding this iframe in Elementor using a shortcode.

The form is successfully integrated in WordPress and is works fine. But as soon as I am clicking on the recorder option to record my video the form is generating an error as the following snippet is attached.

Can anyone let me know what is the possible solution?

I have already added allow camera and microphone parameters in the iframe code in WordPress. But still this issue isn't resolved yet.

Comment: Which error? How do you add camera and microphone access in php? I never heard of something this spectacularly interesting. Please show us the code so we developers can finally see and speak to our servers running php.